# Specify log4net config for use in class library in using/parent project

Tags: c#, dll, log4net

I have implemented log4net in a class library project like so:

```
private static readonly ILog _logger = 
        LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SomeClass));
```

That's all I've done. No config file or anything.

Then in my project that references this class library, I included a log4net config section in the app.config:

```
<log4net>
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
</root>
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <file value="C:/abcd.log" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Now, the log4net logger in the class library project is not able to read the config from its "parent" project, so to speak.

I'm sure I need some more configuration, but I don't know where to start. There are similar questions on stackoverflow etc., but I believe they don't really give an answer on how to do this.

Your help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must tell log4net where to find the logging configuration. How you do it is described in the [log4net Manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html).

I prefer to add `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]` to my application's AssemblyInfo.cs file.

Comment: If you use assembly attributes you must include a call to initialise the log manager in the startup program of the application: "if you use configuration attributes you must invoke log4net to allow it to read the attributes. A simple call to LogManager.GetLogger will cause the attributes on the calling assembly to be read and processed. **Therefore it is imperative to make a logging call as early as possible during the application start-up, and certainly before any external assemblies have been loaded and invoked**. http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#attributes

Comment: Thank you for the addition. As far as I could see, the original poster already does this, so I only added the missing link I could see to make the original posters code work.

Comment: Got it, thank you. I was overthinking it. The class library just uses the log4net config as set by the project that implements it.